# missing run.py from rosjava_bootstrap

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to do the "**Getting started with NXT leJOS, using nxt_lejos_proxy**" tutorial (http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt_lejos_proxy/Tutorials/Getting%20Started#Create_a_Scratch_Package), but when i run "roslaunch proxy.launch" I get this error:

**ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rosjava_bootstrap/run.py]: Cannot locate node of type [run.py] in package [rosjava_bootstrap].**

Looking into my rosjava_bootstrap folder there isn't any run.py file.
I've seen that this file is present in the rosjava electric-tag release (http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/browse/?name=electric-tag) but I don't know how to download it.
Can someone give a tip?

Thank you in advance,

Camilla

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38661/missing-run.py-from-rosjava_bootstrap/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2012-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

leJOS had been updated to use the latest version of rosjava, but the tutorial had not been. The tutorial has now been updated.

---

Originally posted by [LawrieGriffiths](https://answers.ros.org/users/1997/lawriegriffiths/) with karma: 131 on 2012-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1